# How to upload list of images using dio flutter

Tags: flutter, list, api, widget, dio

I have List of images. and i need to upload that list of images from server using dio. and also need to upload using MultipartFile.fromFile in dio.
so, how can i upload it ?

`'document': await MultipartFile.fromFile(file[index].path),`

i try this...

```
for (int index = 0; index < file.length; index++)
      'document': await MultipartFile.fromFile(file[index].path),
```

[image: formdata]
but it's not working. they upload only one image from list.
so is there any other way to upload list of images from server using dio flutter ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by following code:

```
 try {
          FormData formData;
          List<dynamic>? documents = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            String? fileName = file[i]?.path.split('/').last;
            documents.add(await MultipartFile.fromFile(file[i]?.path ?? '', filename: fileName));
          }
          formData = FormData.fromMap({
            'files[]': documents,
          });
          final response = await _dio.post("/medias", data: formData);
          return response.data;
     }
```

Comment: If you find this helpful and working please accept the answer. @Harsh

Answer (score 0):

Inside your upload method:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> postData = Map<String, dynamic>();

postData["attachment[]"] = [];

for (File item in file) {
  postData["attachment[]"].add(await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename: basename(file.path)));
}

final formData = FormData.fromMap(postData);
```

Comment: If you find this solution working, please help upvote the answer. Thank you